# git - forcing merge of branches without any manual conflict resolution

Tags: javascript, node.js, git, merge

Their are many answers to this question but they don't work always.

We have two branches `master` and `master.min`.

```
checked out branch `master.min`

git merge master --strategy-option theirs
```

If some file is deleted in `master` the merge conflicts

So I added code which finds the deleted files and deletes and commits them which fixed the issue.

But now it is again failing for renamed files.

```
Getting diff ...
For minification Added: 6 ,  Modified: 3 ,  Deleted: 2
Total number of files to merge: 38
Diff done!
Merging origin/master into master...
Merging done!
Deleting files from master.min ...
Deleting files done!
Committing delete files ...
Committing delete files done!
Merging master into master.min ...
Error: 'git merge master --strategy-option theirs' exited with error code 1
CONFLICT (rename/delete): go/xl/03/3A.10.T1/Assets/State3/Res2.json deleted in HEAD and renamed in trunk. Version trunk of go/xl/03/3A.10.T1/Assets/State3/Res2.json left in tree.
CONFLICT (rename/delete): go/xl/03/3A.10.T1/Assets/State3/Res1.json deleted in HEAD and renamed in trunk. Version trunk of go/xl/03/3A.10.T1/Assets/State3/Res1.json left in tree.
```